# Selecting from list using chained query

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to build a jquery to select items from an XML file and I can't seem to chain them together correctly.

I've parsed an XML file and appended it to my DOM and this is an example structure

```
<Products>
  <product1>
    <Description>Pound</Description>
    <ProductType>CUR</ProductType>
    <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
    <Rate>1</Rate></ProductRate>
  </product1>
  <product2>
    <Description>Euro</Description>
    <ProductType>TCQ</ProductType>
    <CurrencyCode>Eur</CurrencyCode>
    <Rate>1.5</Rate></ProductRate>
  </product2>
</Products>
```

So what I am trying to do is specify which elements I want to take from the XML and display.  I can select from the XML all items, I can get specific elements but when I try to get all where for example `(ProductType == "CUR")` I can't then select the Code and rate then add to my list.

```
var $xml = $(xml);
var $list = $('#list'); 
    $prodtype = $xml.find("ProductType");

    $prodtype.each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == "CUR"){ 
    $CurrencyCode = $xml.find("CurrencyCode");      
    $CurrencyCode.each(function() {
$( "#list" ).append("<li><a>" + $(this).text() + " </a></li>");
       });
    }
});
```

I think I'm confusing how to select and store the elements. So in psuedo code what I think I am trying to do is

```
for each element where producttype == cur
grab next 2 siblings and append to list
```

Hope this is clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $xml = $(xml);
var $list = $('#list'); 

$prodtype = $xml.find("ProductType");

$prodtype.each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    if( self.text() == "CUR") { 
        var 
            $CurrencyCode = self.next('CurrencyCode')
            $Rate         = $CurrencyCode.next('Rate')          
        ; 
        $( "#list" ).append("<li><a>" + $Rate.text()+$CurrencyCode.text() + " </a></li>");

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to use the parent() method to go up a level, and then back down to the child currency (and rate if applicable).

```
$prodtype.each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == "CUR"){ 
      var $parent = $(this).parent();
      var $CurrencyCode = $parent.find("CurrencyCode");      
      $("#list").append("<li><a>" + $CurrencyCode.text() + " </a></li>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$prodtype.each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == "CUR"){ 
    $CurrencyCode = $(this).siblings().find("CurrencyCode");
    $( "#list" ).append("<li><a>" + $CurrencyCode.text() + " </a></li>");        
    }
});
```

For more on [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use nested calls to [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
$xml.find("ProductType").map(function() {
    return $(this).nextAll().slice(0, 2).map(function() {
        return $("<li><a>" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>");
    });
}).appendTo("#list");
```

The outer call projects the next two siblings from the `<ProductType>` elements, and the inner call projects new list items from the text in these siblings. From there, you can populate your list with a single call to `appendTo()`.